# Disabling Screen Capture in Windows Phone 8 mobile application programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm a newbie to Windows Phone application development.

My project requires disabling the screen capture feature provided by default in Windows Phone 8.

Target Platform - Windows 8

After a long search, found a property "IsScreenCaptureEnabled" in the PhoneApplicationPage class, which can be used to enable/disable the screen capture in windows phones.

Unfortunately, the property is available only from Windows 8.1 and available from Windows Phone 8 Update 3 (GDR3)

For reference,

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Disable-screen-capture-00efe630

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Disable-screen-capture-00efe630/sourcecode?fileId=86655&pathId=2647585

Comment: Why do you need to disable screen capture? Security? Digital rights management? Any resistance is futile. Remember that screen capture is _always_ possible, just use a camera (or second phone) and take a picture of your screen. If that is a problem, redesign your system. Or give in, as resistance really is futile.

Answer (score 0):

It is also supported for GRD2.

See this [link](http://www.pedrolamas.com/2014/01/20/disabling-screenshot-functionality-in-a-windows-phone-app/).Hope that helps.